# Highlight active route in bootstrap nav when using Flow-Router

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, iron-router, flow-router

So I found this [Navigation Bar feature with Bootstrap-3](http://robertdickert.com/blog/2014/05/09/set-up-navigation-with-iron-router-and-bootstrap/), but as of now I am using Flow-Router instead of Iron-Router. Thus I am seeking to transform this helper function into Flow-Router terms:

```
Template.navItems.helpers({
    activeIfTemplateIs: function (template) {
      var currentRoute = Router.current();
      return currentRoute &&
        template === currentRoute.lookupTemplate() ? 'active' : '';
    }
});
```

I have made my own attempt at fixing the problem (haven't bothered testing it though, as many parts of my site/app are still not functional), but I require confirmation in the form of a "yes" or "no" and perhaps a bit more information on what I did wrong.

```
Template.navItems.helpers({
    activeIfTemplateIs: function (template) {
      var currentRoute = FlowRouter.current();
      return currentRoute &&
        template === currentRoute.name ? 'active' : '';
    }
});
```

I guided myself from the [Flow-Router API](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#api). Is this solution correct or is it for one reason or another strictly bound to be used with Iron-Router?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After thinking about your real issue a bit further, I realized I'm doing this is in my app in a completely different way and that perhaps you might find [that pattern](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html) useful. My app also uses bootstrap and has a nav where I want to highlight the active route (and un-highlight all other routes).

In iron-router, I do:

```
onAfterAction(){
  const selector = '.nav a[href="/' + Router.current().route.getName() + '"]'; // the nav item for the active route (if any)
  $('.nav-active').removeClass('nav-active'); // unhighlight any previously highlighted nav
  $(selector).addClass('nav-active'); // highlight the current nav (if it exists, many routes don't have a nav)
}
```

In Flow-Router, `onAfterAction` is replaced by `triggersExit` so you can do:

```
triggersExit(){
  const selector = '.nav a[href="' + FlowRouter.current().path + '"]';
  $('.nav-active').removeClass('nav-active');
  $(selector).addClass('nav-active');
}
```

I found this much more convenient than mucking with the spacebars templates.

FYI, you have a couple options to get the route name:

```
FlowRouter.getRouteName() // reactive
```

or

```
FlowRouter.current().route.name // NOT reactive
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that FlowRouter.getRouteName() is reactive. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use [Active-Route package](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/active-route).

For example:

```
<a class="nav-tab {{isActivePath class='nav-current' path='/new'}}" href="/new">
  New
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a more complete picture, this is what did for my project.

Template HTML Code

```
<template name="topNavbar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Sample</a></li>

    <li class="{{ activeIfTemplateIs 'home' }}">
      <a href="/home">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="{{ activeIfTemplateIs 'users' }}">
      <a href="/users">Users</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
</template>
```

JavaScript Code

```
Template.topNavbar.helpers({
  activeIfTemplateIs: function (template) {
    var currentRoute = FlowRouter.getRouteName();
    return currentRoute && template === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
  }
});
```