# How to remove a class when a different template is rendered in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I am working on a website using Meteor. On one of the pages, I would like some of the images and divs at the top to be animated onto the page.
I have achieved this by adding:

```
Template.home.rendered=function(){
    $('.animateblock').addClass('animated');
};
```

The added class changes some of the css properties, giving me the desired effect.

The problem I am having is that if I go to a different page of the site and then revisit the page with the animations, it doesn't reset. The class is only ever added once, and I haven't been able to figure out a way to have it removed when another page is visited.

My html code is as follows:

```
<div class="textAnimate animateblock">
  <img src="/home/100.png" class="animateblock percent100" alt="100%">
  <img src="/home/antibiotics.png" class="animateblock antibiotic" alt="Antibiotic Free">
  <img src="/home/natural.png" class="animateblock natural" alt="All Natural">
  <div class="horomoneAnimateContainer">
     <div class="animateblock horomoneAnimate">
     <img src="/home/horomone.png" class="horomone" alt="Horomone Free">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stampAnimate animateblock">
  <img src="/home/tasty-stamp.png" class="tasty" alt="Tasty Certified">
</div>
```

I have tried a few different methods, such as adding a removeClass before the addClass, hoping that would fix it, but it did not.

```
Template.home.rendered=function(){
    $('.animateblock').removeClass('animated');
    $('.animateblock').addClass('animated');
};
```

I also tried creating a Template.destroyed section like so, but that didn't work either:

```
Template.home.destroyed=function(){
    $('.animateblock').removeClass('animated');
};
```

I am using Meteor 1.2.0.1 and am also using *iron router*, but haven't been able to find a solution to add and remove classes with it. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32812777/2805154 for manipulating the DOM in i-r `onAfterAction`

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this to call in jQuery on template loads:

```
Template.Messages.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('messageDB', function() {
      $('.loader').delay(300).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.transition-wrapper').delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Meteor Chef has a great resource on loading patterns [here](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/loading-patterns/).